# Ebean ORM 6.x with Play Framework 2.4

Tags: playframework, ebean, mysql-5.7

MySQL 5.7 recently introduced JSON data type, and Ebean ORM repo also included this change [docs](http://%20https://ebean-orm.github.io/apidocs/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/DbJson.html)

When adding SBT of this release to Play project, it doesn't go well.

DDL Generation won't work correctly.

Google [Thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ebean/tcqAvmHf_FI) which has the same discussion.

How do we integrate latest ebean with Play framework 2.4?

Demo project or sample code would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in your project/plugins.sbt change

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" %% "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

to

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" %% "sbt-play-ebean" % "2.0.0")
```